# How to impose memory limits on a shell script?

Tags: bash, ram, resource-limiting

I have a PHP script that, while a folder contains XML files, will process them onto the database.

Currently, the server is running PHP version 5.3.10 and there's a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40479&edit=1) about memory issues triggered by `ZEND_MM_HEAP` within a loop.

This causes the PHP to not free memory properly, thus leading to an error and a script crash:

```
 zend_mm_heap is corrupted
```

<sup>Some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2247977/352449) are found, but I don't have access to the server settings.</sup>

To deal with this, I've prepared the following bash script to take care of the loop, leaving the PHP script only responsible by processing the XML file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check for files to process
# If files are present, call
# the PHP script

DIR="/path/to/dir/with/files"
while [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; do
        php /path/to/php/script/myscript.php
done
```

My goal now is to have this bash memory allocation limited (memory and virtual memory), thus preventing it to hang the system if something goes wrong.

**My Question is:**
How can I limit the memory used by this shell script to a specific amount?

Comment: Please note that you can use change the way the memory is allocated, by running `export USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can limit the memory usage by a Bash Script, doing the follow.

Limit the memory usage by kb (2GB in this example):

```
ulimit -m 2048000
```

Limit virtual memory usage:

```
ulimit -v 2048000
```

Set virtual memory limit to be hard limit, so that process will be killed when exceeding this limit:

```
ulimit -H -v
```

I think this can do what you want.

Comment: Does this limit count for child processes as well? For example, if I spawn an erlang REPL in this bash script, will the memory limit be imposed?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer The limit will be inherited by child processes, so the child processes cannot exceed that. But this limit won't be applied to all process tree.